# User interaction with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which allows a user to interact with a table to create a game of tic-tac-toe, how do I alter it to replace the 'X' and 'O' text with images instead? 
so that when the user clicks on a square an image is displayed instead of plain text ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>tic-tac-toe</title>
  <style>
     td { border: 1px solid black;
          width: 2em;
          height: 2em;
          margin: 0em;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: middle;
     }
     div.RedBG  { background-color: #f00; }
     td.BlueBG  { background-color: white; }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <center><table id="t1"></table></center>
  <div id="m1"></div>
  <script>
     var board = var board = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];
     var free  = 9;
     var turn  = 0;

     function numToLetter(num) {
        switch (num) {
           case 0: return " "
           case 1: return "O"
           case 2: return "X"
        }
     }

     function clearMessage() {
        m1 = document.getElementById("m1");
        m1.style.display = "none";
     }

     function showMessage(message,style) {
        m1 = document.getElementById("m1");
        m1.innerHTML = message;
        m1.style.display = "block";
        m1.className = style;
     }
    ...
```

Comment: `return '<img src="your-image-url.com/x.png">'`?

Comment: the code in the above comment must be appended to the table, the previous td image must be removed as well...

Answer (score 0):

alter the numToLetter function to return a source for an image contained in td or to assign the source to the image...

i think returning the source would be easier and cleaner.

In that case: in the numToLetter calling code assign the source to the appropriate grid square...

```
function numToSource(num) {
    switch (num) {
       case 0: return "path/to/blank.png";
       case 1: return "path/to/O.png";
       case 2: return "path/to/X.png";
    }
 }

function assignImageSource(gridId, num){
      var element = document.getElementById(gridId);
      var source = numberToSource(num);
      element.src = source;  
}
```

Comment: i suppose you could use table indexes instead of element id's for the same effect...

Comment: Use png files so you can utilize empty image backgrounds to allow for color alterations of the backgrounds in javascript or css...